# x11vnc not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vnc

x11vnc used to work fine, but in the new 12.04 release I can't get it to work.

```
16/04/2012 17:22:35 x11vnc version: 0.9.12 lastmod: 2010-09-09  pid: 16524
16/04/2012 17:22:35 XOpenDisplay("") failed.
16/04/2012 17:22:35 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
16/04/2012 17:22:35
16/04/2012 17:22:35 *** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
16/04/2012 17:22:35 *** Trying ":0" in 4 seconds.  Press Ctrl-C to abort.
16/04/2012 17:22:35 *** 1 2 3 4
16/04/2012 17:22:39 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
16/04/2012 17:22:39 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
16/04/2012 17:22:39 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
16/04/2012 17:22:39 Trying again with unset XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME ...
```

I've already tried various kinds of "-auth" parameters, none worked.

Comment: runs fine here.  try setting the DISPLAY environment variable to :0.0 or whatever you have running

Comment: try `xhost +` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the display was running on :1 in stead of :0

Executing `w` in the terminal told me that much

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got it work by using the lightdm auth file:

```
root@kbrandt-desktop:~# ps wwwwaux | grep auth
root      1815  0.3  1.2  69320 51980 tty7     Ss+  19:11   0:02 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
root      5870  0.0  0.0   4372   828 pts/0    S+   19:25   0:00 grep auth
root@kbrandt-desktop:~# x11vnc -forever -httpdir /usr/share/vnc-java -noxdamage -httpport 5900 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0
```